# Tamporarily saving and sanitizing image objects in Django

Tags: python, django, file, temporary-files

I'm creating a Django website where users post details of used items they want to sell/barter.

When posting an item, the second-last step is to upload (upto 3) photos of the item on sale. The last step is to provide personal details (name, address, mobile). After this, the ad is finalized and goes into a "pending approval" queue.

I don't want to save photos to the DB *until an advert is finalized*. Hence I'm thinking I'll temporarily save a reference to the [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) object retrieved from the form like so:

```
request.session["photo"] = form.cleaned_data.get('photo',None)
```

So far so good, or is this problematic? Assuming everything is correct so far.

Next, once ad is final, I'll save the images to my storage backend and **pop** `photo` from the `request.session` dictionary.

But what if the user drops out before finalizing the ad? How would I handle cases where a `request.session["photo"]` entry was created, *but the user never finished the ad*? Where are UploadedFile objects saved?

Basically, I need an efficient way to process 'orphaned' request.session image entries and related UploadedFile objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem of using sessions is that they're not meant to handle a lot amount of data, and they could potentially loss information due to encoding, the RAM filling up, the framework's process of garbage collection, and such. That really dependes on how you store sessions objects, if you already solved this problem, go to step two.

**Step One:** You may want to make a separate model to store the image temporarily, storing the date and image file reference (through an ImageField), you can tell this model to upload the file to a temporary location on the Media directory using the `upload_to` parameter of the field.

**Step Two:** Set up a management command that filters the orphaned models from a certain date (images older than 10 minutes or so), and then deletes them along with the images (this is very important, as deleting the database record does not delete the file). The management command should be able to run without user intervention. [Read more about management commands here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/)

**Step Three:** Set up your machine's Crontab or whatever you use to schedule processes, to run the management command in a daily or hourly basis depending on your needs.

Comment: I have celery queues set up. Should I just schedule a daily celery task to to take care of orphaned models?

Comment: Secondly: just saw this old post: http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2010/03/02/dont-delete-image-file-when-deleting-django-model-instance/ It seems when a model instance is deleted, there's no need to delete the underlying file manually in Django?

Comment: A Celery queue will do just fine, you don't even need to make a management command in that case, just a function that handles the models. Also, that post is old, file deletion was removed in Django 1.3 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6456