# Render images from media directory Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model to store images of all users. Each user will have an uploaded image as well a thumbnail image. All the images will be stored in the path 
`'/media/users/<username>/user_image.jpg'`
Say the user is ABC:
directory structure will be: `/media/users/ABC/ABC_image.jpg` and `/media/users/ABC/thumbnail/ABC_image.img`

I could get the path of the image from the `ImageField` of this particular User model. I have a template where I want to display this image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in `settings.py` and in `urls.py`.

Answer (score 2):

to display the media file, you need to configure your settings.py as,

```
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'your_media_directory')
```

and in your project's urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in your template,

```
<img src="{{your_model_instance.image_field.url}}"/>
```

Comment: In my middleware, I set request.session['user_image']= model_instance.image_field.url and I'm using this session variable in all the templates to display profile pictures in all the pages like this, `<img src="{{request.session.user_image}}" class="rounded-circle z-depth-0" alt="avatar image" width="30" height="30">`

Is it a correct way of doing it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610533/tamporarily-saving-and-sanitizing-image-objects-in-django would be the answer you're looking for